# laravel 4: aws - use custom config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-4, config

I use larvel 4 with AWS sdk. I want to add another AWS service with different key and region. when I used only one AWS service for example SES I put my key in /app/config/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel just in the array `'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',` all works well now I want add another service for example S3. so I create custom config file in the same directory:

configaws.php (with chmod 777):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Create a client that uses the us-west-1 region
$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxx',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1'
));

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxx',
    'region' => 'us-west-2'
));
```

and use this line in my config.php file `'config_file' => 'configaws.php',`
the problem is that Laravel can't find this file, I got exception 'Unable to open configaws.php for reading'.

my simple question is where I should put my `configaws.php` file?
because I try a lot of options and nothing works for me.

is there another option to use 2 different keys for amazon services?

```
solution:
I used amazon's service IAM to create new user with permissions for S3 and SES
and used his key for my app.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Laravel 4.1+, The best way store sensitive information using `dot` files.

> For "real" applications, it is advisable to keep all of your sensitive configuration out of your configuration files. Things such as database passwords, Stripe API keys, and encryption keys should be kept out of your configuration files whenever possible. So, where should we place them? Thankfully, Laravel provides a very simple solution to protecting these types of configuration items using "dot" files.

Assume your environment is `production` or you can check your environment by reading the following doc.

http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

For production environment, create a `.env.php` in the project root of your application and add the AWS information like so.

```
// .env.php
<?php

return array(
    //SesClient
    'AWS_SES_KEY'      => 'XXX',
    'AWS_SES_SECRET'   => 'XXX',
    'AWS_SES_REGION'   => 'XXX',

   //S3Client
    'AWS_S3_KEY'      => 'XXX',
    'AWS_S3_SECRET'   => 'XXX',
    'AWS_S3_REGION'   => 'XXX',

);
```

Now, when you need the api information, use the PHP's super global variables `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER` to retrieve the information. For example, to retrieve the Amazon s3 api info, you can do the following:

```
<?php
echo $_ENV['AWS_S3_KEY'];
echo $_ENV['AWS_S3_SECRET'];
```

For more information please check the Laravel documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration